# Call / fire function when click on same option from dropdown list which was previously selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Here, I am going to explain what I need to do.

I need that when the user click the same option from the dropdown list / select list (after clicking on dropdown list) which was previous selected, then a function should fire.

My question is that how I fire/call a function when the user click the same option from the dropdown list which was previous selected.

I know the 'onchange' event function will fire / call only when we change the options otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

Check for selected in the onClick. Here is an example for columns of pics (thats why the check for current column).

```js
onDoubleTap = () => {
  let showFull = this.props.appState.speciesShowFull;
  let fullAction = showFull ? 'speciesShowBody' : 'speciesShowFull';
  this.props.appAppActions(fullAction);
};
clickHandler = () => {
  if ((this.props.isCurrentColumn) && (this.props.index == this.props.selected)) {
    this.onDoubleTap();
  } else {
    this.props.clickHandler(this.props.item, this.props.index);
  }
};
```